# Modal dialog close icon alignment with CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When i am trying to align the close icon over the modal dialog header strip, then its not getting aligned. The header strip gets struck beside the close button only. Its not moving further. My idea is to keep the close icon over the dialog box header strip. Something like this? See below.

[image]

But i am getting like this. See below.

[image]

See my code below what i have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" style=" width: 100%; height: 24%; margin: -16px -17px 0 -16px; padding: 10px 0 8px 0; background-color: #2196f3; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So how can i achieve this? Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: check with the margin and padding for `modal-title`

Comment: I tired adding both padding and margin to modal-title but nothing working for both of them.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style of your `<h4>` is messing up the way it looks. Change it to your `header div` and remove the negative margin like so:

```
<div class="modal-header" style=" width: 100%; height: 24%; margin: 0 padding: 10px 0 8px 0; background-color: #2196f3; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/go/e9P15Afk3W)

Answer (score 0):

Add padding and background-color to modal-header.Remove them in modal-title